# Как сделать в UICollectionView только один ряд по горизонтали?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Привет всем! Я добавил `UICollectionView` как `SubView` в другой контроллер, задал frame в данном родительском контроллере для `UICollectionView` view, сделал Scroll по горизонтали. Я хочу чтобы у меня отображался только один ряд items и можно было делать скролл по горизонтали, но у меня отображается 2 ряда ( на самом деле если поднять по Y то будут отображаться еще несколько рядов). Я пробовал несколько разных методов, но они не помогали мне. Так же пробовал если сделать в IB с помощью `UIContainerController`, это работает, но мне нужно сделать это в коде. Как я могу это исправить?

Мой код который добавляет `UICollectionView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addUIElements()
}

// MARK: - UI functions

private func addUIElements() {
    view.addSubview(headerView)

    let lifelineController = StoryboardManager.lifeLineStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LifeLineCollectionViewController") as! LifeLineCollectionViewController
    addChildViewController(lifelineController)
    lifelineController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: headerView.frame.height, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(lifelineController.view)
    lifelineController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Мой результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо при создании своего `UICollectionView` указать ему, как вы хотите располагать элементы. Это делается при помощи передачи своего кастомного лэйаут класса в метод

```
- initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:
```

До этоо вам надо сделать свой сабкласс `UICollectionViewLayout` наследованный от `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, который вы будете передавать при инициализации `UICollectionView` и в нем в ините указать

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10000.0f;
    }
    return self; 
}
```